# Wifi not working after Bootcamp setup

Tags: mac, wifi, bootcamp, windows

So I just used Bootcamp to install the Windows 10 technical preview and all was working well until I couldn't find the Wi-fi settings. I have trawled through everything and it seems to be a problem with my drivers. (I could not find BC support software from Apple for Windows 10). I have no idea why I can't connect to the internet on windows and no idea on how to fix it. If you look up the issue on the internet there always seems to be something that they have that I don't (Such as a WINSTALL Drive.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Boot Camp drivers are downloaded via Apple Software Update inside Windows. Of course, that's a bit Catch 22 if you don't have a net connection...

Comment: @Tetsujin: Actually, your comment is false. If you have a older Mac running Windows 10, Apple Software Update will not download Boot Camp drivers or updates for Boot Camp itself. Apple Software Update will download updates for iTunes, iCloud and QuickTime.

Comment: What kind of Mac do you have? Some of the earlier versions of Macs cannot support Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Apple does not support running Windows 10 on Macs older than the 2012 models. This does mean you can not run Windows 10 on an older model, just that you are *on your own* to figure out how.

Windows is designed to use older drivers when newer ones can not be found. The drivers for Apple hardware is included in the "Boot Camp Support Software" (BCSS). If Apple did not supply Windows 10 BCSS for your Mac, you should use latest available BCSS that **Apple documents is designed for your Mac**.

One myth I put to test was: "Downloading the BCSS using the Boot Camp 
Assistant will produce newer software than directly downloading from the internet". I have iMac (21.5" mid 2011) running OS X 10.11.3. I used the Boot Camp Assistant to download the BCSS for Windows 8.1 to a flash drive. I also directly downloaded the BCSS for Windows 7 from [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US). I then used Windiff.exe to compare both downloads. They were identical. I am not saying this is true for all Macs, it just happened to be true for mine.

To install the BCSS after Windows is installed, open the BootCamp folder and execute the `setup.exe` application. If setup.exe will not execute, right click on the icon and select **Trouble compatibility**.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't install the drivers: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990 and http://www.theverge.com/2015/8/13/9147657/apple-boot-camp-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, even with all the latest Apple drivers. [This video](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pBNdOMX3y5A) helped me. It's just toggling one preference, and you're good. Very simple, but it should've worked out the box, so to speak.

Comment: If it is as simple as claimed add a short written answer and not a linked video!

Comment: Agreed, but still appreciated the info nonetheless :)